# Services - Rest Server Setup

Tags: drupal, rest, service

I have the Services 6.x-2.4 module installed on a Drupal 6 site.
I am attempting to use REST but I am having difficulties getting things working.

For instance, **http://mysite.com/services/xmlrpc** returns some kind of feedback that the server is working.
While **http://mysite.com/services/rest** returns nothing and I am not sure if the server is actually working.

Can anyone offer some direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an endpoint configured and enabled.  You'll have to additionally enable resources for the endpoint.